# leaflet coordinates not working

Tags: leaflet, coordinates

[Leaflet Maps Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6sU3.png)

KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>

<Placemark>
  <name>10 Downing Street</name>
  <description>Test</description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>45.7251809,-75.0467511,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>

</Document>
</kml>
```

Why the point is not showing at the exact LAT/LONG, it show on top of the leaflet map...

Google map show the correct lat [Google Maps](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/45%C2%B043'30.7%22N+75%C2%B002'48.3%22W/@45.7251846,-75.0489398,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d45.7251809!4d-75.0467511?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

I just figured that Leaflet KML coordinates is LNG, LAT and not LAT, LNG

Switching coordinates made it all work